# Customizing Rails XML rendering to include extra properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-serialization

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
create_table :ninjas do |t|
  t.string name
end
```

And the Ninja class with an extra property:

```
class Ninja < ActiveRecord::Base
  def honorific
    "#{name}san"
  end
end
```

And in my controller I just want to render it to XML:

```
def show
  render :xml => Ninja.find(params[:id])
end
```

The honorific part isn't rendered. That makes sense, since it's just a method, but is there a way of tricking it?

I'm totally up for answers to the effect of, "You're doing this totally wrong." I'll just add that I really do want to calculate the honorific on the fly, and not, like, store it in the database or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:methods` argument to `to_xml` for this serialization. You can either call it directly in your action...

```
render xml: Ninja.find(params[:id]).to_xml(methods: :honorific)
```

...or redefine `to_xml` in your `Ninja` class to always include it.

Take a look at [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001366) for more info.